# How to perfectly use KPL/KCL with spring-cloud-stream-binder-aws-kinesis lib?

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-stream, amazon-kcl, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis

I've decided to use spring-cloud-stream-binder-aws-kinesis lib on version 4.0.1, but I have some questions about how I can implement KPL/KCL with it. I'm currently following this guide on how to utilize the properties: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-aws-kinesis/blob/main/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis-docs/src/main/asciidoc/overview.adoc

From what I tested, if I set `kplKclEnabled` to true, the enhanced fan-out feature is also enabled by default. Is that statement true? If so, is there a way to avoid using the enhanced fan-out but keep utilizing the KPL/KCL?

With the `kplKclEnabled`, I also tried to reduce the throughput over my KCL - because I was getting some errors over my applications for I was receiving too much data - by changing the `consumerBackoff` and `recordsLimit` default values. Still, it doesn't seem to be affecting the consumer. Does anyone know of a way for me to reduce the throughput? Is it something that I can manage? More importantly, and if I am not asking too much, do you know more details about these settings along with `idleBetweenPolls`?

Answer (score 1):

Starting with that `4.0.1` version there is option for the consumer:

> fanOut:: The KCL retrieval mode: `true` - fan-out, `false` - polling.

The `recordsLimit` and `idleBetweenPolls` are not propagated to the `KclMessageDrivenChannelAdapter`.

Feel free to raise a GH issue for Spring Integration AWS to expose those options for the `KclMessageDrivenChannelAdapter`. However they still will be used only for polling mode.

Comment: Thank you for reaching out. In that particular case you mentioned about the retrieval mode, if I turn it to false (to enable the polling mode), will the Enhanced Fan-Out also be turned off? I was doing some tests with this feature (true and false), but the result was the same despite turning it off. The kinesis data stream kept turning the enhanced fan-out on

Comment: If I am not asking too much. Let's say that I have millions of events on the Kinesis Data Stream. Does this lib do something to handle all this data without having backpressure problems? I know that KCL already has some mechanisms to handle this, especially with checkpoints and lease threads, but I wonder if having too much data already stored over the KDS could cause some problems

Comment: That is probably outside of our control internally in the KCL. If you do `spring.cloud.stream.kinesis.bindings.<BINDING_NAME>.consumer.fan-out=false`, it is propagated down to the KCL config. The rest is out of our control.

Comment: This Spring Cloud Stream Binder is just a thin wrapper around KCL, so whatever you would expect from there is applied here as well. The rest is up to you how you handle that data in your application when records are delivered to your consumer.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. Talking about the fanout, should I open an issue on GH? I was checking using AWS and localstack, and even though informing the fanOut = false, it keeps creating the KDS (or changing if it already exists) to Enhanced FanOut mode. I don't see this behavior when using KCL without Spring Cloud Stream Binder

Comment: Sorry if it looked like that, and I got that it is just a thin wrapper. I didn't understand why this different behavior (Enhanced FanOut enabling on Kinesis Binder even though setting to false) compared to using the pure KCL

Comment: We need to understand what you really are looking for. To use KCL and disable its fan-out with the Kinesis Binder you need to have `kplKclEnabled = true` as the binder property and `fanOut = false` as a consumer property. With pure KCL you have to provide that `PollingConfig` into the `RetrievalConfig`. Any chance that you can share a simple project to confirm otherwise then?